# Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

i am getting this error but cocoapods is installed on my computer.

> Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
> CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
> Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
> For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
> To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
> CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
> Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

In my case, I use Bundler to install all required tools, also Cocoapods. But when I call `bundle exec fastlane ios ...`, I get this error message.

Long story short: You need to update Bundler.

The error appears because Flutter is not able to verify the version of Cocoapds you have installed, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/macos/cocoapods.dart#L117

But why can't Flutter verify the Cocoapods version?

When you call `bundle exec pod --version`, you get this output:

```
$ bundle exec pod --version
Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
1.11.2
```

This `Calling 'DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge! ...` is the problem, if you fix it, Flutter can build you app.

To fix it, call `bundle update --bundler`, see https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/5234